# How do I fix the error "The specified deps.json [] does not exist" for a .NET 8.0 Web Assembly Standalone app using EF and SQLServer?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am very new in Blazor WebAssembly but i have some experience in ASP.net MVC.
The youtube tutorial told to write

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {"DBConnection": "server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;database=EmployeeDB;Trusted_Connection=true"
```

in AppSettings.json  but my project doesn't have so I wrote it in LaunchSetting.json

The youtube tutorial told to write

```
        "services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection")));"
```

in Startup.cs  but my project doesn't have so I wrote it in program.cs

Then after that in Package Manager Console in ran the command "Add-Migration InitialCreate", and I got the error message "The specified deps.json [] does not exist".

Please help me. Thank you very much.

I have tried many things but failed.

Comment: Blazor WebAssembly stand alone app is a single page application which is similar to React Angular, but the connectionstring configuration should be used in a server side application like MVC project you are fimilar with to connect to the database.... For standalone Blazor WebAssembly apps, there's no .NET server-side dependency after the app is downloaded from the server, so the app remains functional if the server goes offline.

Comment: you should have another web app like api app or MVC app used to offer data support  for the blazor app, then connect to database inside the API or MVC app.

Comment: I see ,that means I must have at least 2 projects in my solution.
In .Net Core 5.0 solution , we used to have 3 projects  called BlazorProject.Client , BlazorProject.Server , BlazorProject.Shared by default.
But why in .Net Core 8.0 solution , we go only 1 project by default, it mislead me that we only 1 project is needed.

Comment: `BlazorProject.Client , BlazorProject.Server , BlazorProject.Shared` indicates that when you create the project from template, you checked the `asp.net core hosted`. If you don't pick that option, you will only have the client project.... But in .net 8, we have the template for `stand alone` which is the  same. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IyoJ.png Do you have any other concerns on it?